# Can you use JW Player on an Element in a Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jwplayer, flutter-web

#### Presupposition

Because of the way HTML elements work in *Flutter Web* (not relevant to the concept of the question), I **necessarily** have my `div` element that I want to [use `jwplayer` on](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-embed-a-player#section-basic-content-playback) in a **shadow DOM**.

#### Setup

I have a `<div id="foo-player">` in a [shadow root](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) as the child of node in the body of my document. The JW Player `<script>` is included in the `<head>` of my document.

### The player

The player can easily be set up on *any `<div>`*:

```dart
jwplayer("foo-player").setup(..)
// or
jwplayer(divElement).setup(..)
```

I found out that you can use any DOM element object in [the source code](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/blob/master/src/js/jwplayer.js#L42).

#### By ID

I cannot use `jwplayer("foo-player")` because the shadow DOM obviously hides the element from the document, so `document.getElementById` does not work.

#### By element

I can use `document.getElementById('shadow-dom-host').shadowRoot.getElementById('foo-player')` (where `shadow-dom-host` is the DOM element that hosts the shadow DOM) and pass that element to `jwplayer`.

I can successfully call `setup` on the resulting object, so JW Player seems to accept it, however, I do not **see** it.

### The problem

I think that the latter attempt does not work because the CSS etc. is still hidden from the shadow DOM, which means that the `jwplayer` will still not be able to work with the shadow DOM.

## Question

Is there any way I can run the `jwplayer` *inside of the **shadow DOM***, so that it will be able to work with the `<div>` element in the shadow DOM?

Comment: Technically, it works, but it's not visible. I don't understand why would you look to setup the player inside a shadow element and then expect it to work. What's the goal? Could you also create a sample?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy No, Flutter actually takes care of displaying the shadow elements. If I look at the element in the inspector, it is not modified - I think that JW Player will only modify the passed object, but not actually modify the DOM element in the shadow DOM.

Comment: Do create a snippet please, it'd be easier taking a look into it :)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy That snippet would have a huge overhead because of Flutter. I managed to find a workaround by placing both `jwplayer` and the `div` **inside of an `iframe`** and I place that iframe in the shadow DOM. I will have to see if I can get everything to work and then I would post it as an answer. Even if it is not ideal.

Comment: Or try giving a small bounty to get more attention if you feel like it, the question is interesting :)